# Reduce total number of SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to reduce the total number of sql queries sent to my RedShift cluster by combining 2 queries into one.

Here is my scenario.

- Given a card number range, determine which cards within that range have had a transaction yesterday.
- For each of these cards, determine their last recorded transaction (if any).

Here's my current, slow but correct approach:

```
query1 = '''SELECT card_no, timestamp, code_one, transaction_amount
        FROM table1
        WHERE card_no BETWEEN %s AND %s
        AND code_one = 202
        AND code_two = 0
        AND timestamp < date_trunc('day', CURRENT_DATE)
        AND timestamp >= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 days')
        ORDER BY card_no, timestamp DESC''' % (card_from, card_to)

query2 = '''SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE card_number = %s
        ORDER BY transaction_date DESC LIMIT 1''' % card_no
```

This approach generates correct output. 
Query1 is run first and creates files of transactions based on different ranges. 
I then run query2 on each card_no in those files and perform some logic operations to get my final output.

My dataset now contains over 4000 card ranges, each returning between 30 and 100 cards with transactions. The number of queries quickly increases out of my control.
Is there a way I can combine these two queries into one to drastically reduce the total number of queries?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does `FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.card_no = table2.card_number`  somehow not do the right thing for you? If you do that you get what you need in a single query.

Comment: do you have a relation between these two tables.. if you have you can simply join them with left join

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work. I just want to append to the result of query 1, the results of query 2 but since query 2 depends on query 1, I can't seem to find the logic around that.

Comment: Are you always going to get all data for all card ranges (currently through multiple queries)?  If so, why filter by that at all rather than just get all the data at once?

Comment: Each card range contains many card numbers, most of which have not had a transaction yesterday. The first check is to filter only the cards that had a transaction yesterday. The second check is to see, out of these card numbers, which ones have had transactions before and which have not. Hope this clears it up a little.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to create a join and use `MAX()` aggregation function

```
SELECT
    table1.card_no AS card_no,
    table1.timestamp AS timestamp,
    table1.code_one AS code_one,
    table1.transaction_amount AS transaction_amount,
    MAX(transaction_date) AS max_trans_date
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
  ON table1.card_no = table2.card_number
WHERE table1.card_no BETWEEN %s AND %s
AND table1.code_one = 202
AND code_two = 0
AND table1.timestamp < date_trunc('day', CURRENT_DATE)
AND table1.timestamp >= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 days')
GROUP BY card_no
ORDER BY card_no
```

Those records with non-null values for `max_trans_date` will be the cards that had previous transaction on table2.  If you change LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN you will only get those cards with previous transactions.  If you use LEFT JOIN with addition filter in where clause `AND max_trans_date IS NULL` you will get only those cards without previous transactions.

Comment: I like the idea and I think this one is close but your query will not run without the other members of the select statement inside the group by clause. Also this will replace records from query 1 with records from query 2 rather than append them

Comment: @Zihs The query will run and assuming that there is only one record per card id in table 1, there will not be any problem with the aggregation.  If there are multiple records per card_no in table 1, then you would need to specify aggregation functions on the other table1 columns or you will get unpredictable results.  I guess I don't know what you mean by replace or append.  This is strictly a SELECT, it is not going to change any data at all.  If you update your question with actual table schema information and sample data, as well as what you are expecting as final output that would help.